# How to detect the spawn failure in expect command

Tags: shell-script, expect, ttyusb

I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

expect -c "
spawn cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 115200
expect \"foo\"
send \"bar\"
"

echo $?
```

And I run it without `/dev/ttyUSB0`:

```
$ ls /dev/ttyUSB0
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB0': No such file or directory

$ ./test.sh
spawn cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 115200
cu: open (/dev/ttyUSB0): No such file or directory
cu: /dev/ttyUSB0: Line in use
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send "bar""
0
```

Why `expect` returns `0`?
How can I detect the `spawn` failure?

Answer (score 2):

You could test for `foo` *and* `eof`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    spawn cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 115200
    expect {
        eof {
            puts stderr "Cannot open cu"
            exit 1
        }
        "foo"
    }
    send "bar"
END_EXPECT

echo $?
```

I find it easier to use a here-doc than a quoted string to contain the expect code. The quoted here-doc means you don't have to worry about escaping `\$expect_variables` as well.

Comment: I could detect disconnections by ```eof```.
Thank you!